# Symfony - ParamConverter : manual attributes "enabled" and "deleted"

Tags: symfony, annotations, symfony-3.4

I'm working on :

- Symfony 3.4.14
- SensionExtraFrameworkBundle 5.2.0

Before I used this method to get my campaign inside my controller :

```
<?php

/**
* @Route("/{slug}", name="homepage")
*/

public function indexAction($slug)
{
    ......->findOneBy([ 'slug" = $slug, 'deleted' = 0, 'enabled' = 1 ])
}
```

Then I decided to use a `@ParamConverter` annotation to auto select the good Campaign object. It works perfect :

```
<?php

/**
* @Route("/{slug}", name="homepage")
* @ParamConverter("campaign", options={"mapping":{ "slug" = "slug" }})
*/

public function indexAction(Campaign $campaign)
{

}
```

However, my entity also contains 2 attributes `deleted` and `enabled` and I don't know how to include it into the `mapping` option. Below is what I already tried :

```
<?php

/**
* @Route("/{slug}", name="homepage")
* @ParamConverter("campaign", options={"mapping":{ "slug" = "slug", "deleted" = "0", "enabled" = "1" }})
*/

public function indexAction(Campaign $campaign)
{

}
```

Quotes / No quotes for the "0" value = same result.
Any idea ?

Comment: I suppose you could try adding a requirements section to your route and set values for deleted and enabled.  So then in your mapping you would have "deleted" = "deleted".  But too much magic for me.  Adding a repository function as the answer below suggests along with an [expression](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html#fetch-via-an-expression) might also work.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom repository functionwhich retrieve the Entity by the slug and the 2 others fields.

```
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Entity;

/**
* @Route("/{slug}", name="homepage")
* @Entity("campaign", expr="repository.findActive(slug)")
*/
public function indexAction(Campaign $campaign)
{}
```

Then, craete a `findActive` function in the CampaignRepository. You will be able to filter on enabled and deleted field.

Dont't forget to set the repositoryClass in the Entity Annotation.

If another way exists to achieve this goal, I'm curious to know

Comment: Thans for your answer @G1.3. In  fact, creating a new custom repository would be longer than using my first ">findOneBy([ 'slug" = $slug, 'deleted' = 0, 'enabled' = 1 ])". Than I will keep it ;)

Comment: Yes, its longer for the first time only. And, with a repository and a ParamConverter, you will have a simpler 404 management and reusability for others actions/functions